# Are general surface of high degree in $P^3$ dominated by subvarieties of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a general surface in $P^3$ of degree sufficiently large, can it be dominated by subvariety of some abelian variety?

(The motivation is to understand if Bombieri-Lang conjecture holds for general type surfaces, the conjecture is known for subvarieties of abelian varieties)

[the previous version of the question asked if the surfaces are birational to subvarieties of P^3, this is impossible and is resolved in the comments]

Comment: Any map of $X$ into an abelian variety factors through $\operatorname{Alb}(X)$. Over $\mathbb{C}$ at least, the dimension of $\operatorname{Alb}(X)$ is $h^{1,0}(X)$ which is zero by the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem. So any map from $X$ to an abelian variety is constant.

Comment: And the same goes for rational maps, by elimination of indeterminacy plus birational invariance of $H^0(X,\Omega_X)$ for smooth proper varieties.

Comment: This is true for any surface: For $X$ a surface and $A$ a high-dimensional abelian variety, a general two-dimensional complete intersection in $X \times A$ will be (isomorphic to) a subvariety of $A$ and will dominate $X$.

Comment: This is true for any projective variety $X$: Choose an embedding $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$. Choose an abelian variety $A$ and a surjective (even finite) morphism $A\to \mathbb{P}^n$. Let $Z = X\times_{\mathbb{P}^n} A$. Note that $Z\to X$ is surjective (even finite if you like). Moreover, $Z\subset A$. (You can also take a suitable connected component $Z'$ of $Z$ to get a connected $Z'\subset A$ that dominates $X$.)